# Getting events as Json through Facebook API in Java

Tags: java

Right now I use a URL object to work with a FacebookModel object:

```
public ImageIcon getIconImage(String id) throws IOException {
    String url = "http://graph.facebook.com/" + id + "/picture" ; 
    URL pic = new URL(url); 
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(pic);
    return  icon;
}
```

I use (for image Icons) :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {         
    try {
        center.setIcon(model.getIconImage(display.getText())); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SubmitAction.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

How can I get user's events in the same way.

Thanks.